# Fork Crypto from go-ethereum (geth)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, blockchain-fork, openblockchain

I have clone the source code of go-ethereum from github and i want to modify it so i can get owner crypto.

Step 1: go run mkalloc.go genesis.json from go-ethereum/core it gen hex for mainnetAllocData

Step 2: added it to genesis_alloc.go

Step 3: go test cpu -8

Step 4: fix hash test for new generate hash into params/config.go

Step 5: rerun go test cpu -8

Steo 6: make geth

I have read the reference but I do not know the next step how, can someone show me or give me link, please.

Is there references or link that i use to learn how to create wallet, transaction, smart contract,...????